# Different date to timestemp value in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, timestamp

Here is date converted from `0` timestemp in `PHP` :

```
echo date('d-m-Y h:i:s', strtotime(0));

Output : 01-01-1970 08:00:00
```

Then if i convert this date to timestemp in `javascript` :

```
var dateToTimestemp = new Date('01-01-1970 08:00:00').getTime();

Output : 9000000
```

```js
var dateToTimestemp = new Date('01-01-1970 08:00:00').getTime();
document.write(dateToTimestemp);
```

**Question**

> Why `javascript` return `9000000` not `0` ?

Thank you !

Comment: What is the timezone setting for your server running PHP? Timestamp 0 is 00:00 UTC on 1/1/1970; but using date() will adjust that for your timezone

Comment: FWIW: "timestamp" (with an "a"), not "timestemp". :-)

Comment: `echo date('d-m-Y h:i:s', strtotime(0));` isn't sensible either; use `echo date('d-m-Y h:i:s', 0);` because integer `0` is a meaningless string for a date/time value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two reasons:

1. Your string is not in any format that [the specification defines](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-date-time-string-format), which means that the JavaScript engine can fall back on its own *"...implementation-specific heuristics or implementation-specific date formats..."* It might use local time, or it might use UTC, you can't know for sure unless you test each JavaScript engine the code may run on, because it's implementation-specific.
2. You've specified `8:00`, which means you're relying on it being interpreted as local time.

You have two options: Either use a form that will reliably be in UTC and specify a UTC time (e.g., 0 instead of 8 for hours), or use a form that will reliably be in local time (and specify 8 for hours).

If you want to use UTC, provide it in the format defined by the spec, with a `Z`:

```js
console.log(
  new Date('1970-01-01T00:00:00Z').getTime()
);
```

If you want it in local time specifying 8 as the hour, use the long form of the `Date` constructor:

```js
console.log(
  new Date(1970, 0, 1, 8).getTime()
  //             ^--- 0 = January
);
```

You *should* be able to use `new Date('1970-01-01T08:00:00')` without the `Z` for local time, but unfortunately this is a part of the spec that's gone back-and-forth, so you'd need to test that carefully with your target browsers because different browsers have adopted different generations of the spec at different times. Whereas the long form constructor is reliably local time cross-browser.

Comment: 2) is wrong. If you use '00:00' instead of '08:00', the result is -3600000

Comment: @moon: Did you read #1? You're clearly in a time zone in GMT+1000. You can't just fix one of the issues, you have to fix **both**.

Comment: You answer help me a lot ! Thank you @T.J.Crowder !

Answer (score 0):

**PHP and JavaScript is not same**

You put nothing in php it will take its default and JavaScript will take its default value.

PHP default it `01-01-1970 12:00:00` and Javascipt default date is `1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z`

Php demo : https://eval.in/911912

Check in JS

```js
console.log(new Date(0));
```

Even it is different in chrome and firefox

```js
console.log(new Date("0"));
```

Thats why you are getting different value in both . Why not you validate you value first and put into these methods

Comment: *"Javascipt default date is 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"* No, it isn't. The closest thing to a default date is "now" (`new Date()`).